# How to capture repeated occurrence using python 3 regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Consider sentence : W U T Sample A B C D

I'm trying to use `re.groups` after `re.search` to fetch A, B, C, D (letters in caps after 'Sample'). There could be variable number of letters

Few unsuccessful attempts :

```
A = re.search('Sample\s([A-Z])\s*([A-Z])*', 'W U T Sample A B C D')
A.groups()
('A', 'B')

A = re.search('Sample\s([A-Z])(\s*([A-Z]))*', 'W U T Sample A B C D')
A.groups()
('A', ' D', 'D')

A = re.search('Sample\s([A-Z])(?:\s*([A-Z]))*', 'W U T Sample A B C D')
A.groups()
('A', 'D')
```

I'm expecting `A.groups()` to give `('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')`

Taking another example, 'XSS 55 D W Sample R G Y BH' should give the output `('R', 'G', 'Y', 'B', 'H')`

Comment: You can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/FhNfHN/1/)

Comment: @CodeManiac Useful tool, but the example regex mentioned does not give ('R', 'G', 'Y', 'B', 'H') for 'XSS 55 D W Sample R G Y BH'. B and H are considered one, which is different from what I want

Comment: You need to split the matched group in next step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most regex engines, including Python's, will overwrite a repeating capture group.  So, the repeating capture group you see will just be the final one, and your current approach will not work.  As a workaround, we can try first isolating the substring you want, and then applying `re.findall`:

```
input = "W U T Sample A B C D"
text = re.search(r'Sample\s([A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*)', input).group(1)  # A B C D
result = re.findall(r'[A-Z]', text)
print(result)

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose two steps would be involved for this.